# Problems installing Nginx+Rtmp on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nginx, rtmp

Unsuccessfully can't complete the installation using this guide: `https://docs.peer5.com/guides/setting-up-hls-live-streaming-server-using-nginx/` 
I always when to try push stream from other server using FFmpeg I get TCP&RTMP error.

[The Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZDrH.png)

I'm installing nginx using these commands:

```
    apt-get update

    sudo apt install nginx

    sudo apt install libnginx-mod-rtmp

    apt install git

    cd /usr/src
    git clone git clone https://github.com/sergey-dryabzhinsky/nginx-rtmp-module.git

sudo apt-get install build-essential libpcre3 libpcre3-dev libssl-dev

wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.10.1.tar.gz
tar -xf nginx-1.10.1.tar.gz
cd nginx-1.10.1

./configure --with-http_ssl_module --add-module=../nginx-rtmp-module
make -j 1
sudo make install

conf file

    nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

for this command `sudo apt install libnginx-mod-rtmp` i get this error `E: Unable to locate package libnginx-mod-rtmp

And here is my Nginx conf file very simple:

```
worker_processes  auto;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

# RTMP configuration
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
        chunk_size 4000;

        application show {
            live on;
            # Turn on HLS
            hls on;
            hls_path /mnt/hls/;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;
            # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
            deny play all;
        }
    }
}

http {
    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    directio 512;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
            # Disable cache
            add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';

            # CORS setup
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

            # allow CORS preflight requests
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }

            types {
                application/dash+xml mpd;
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
            }

            root /mnt/;
        }
    }
}
```

Asking for your expertise to guide me the right solution, regards

Answer (score 0):

You need at least Ubuntu Bionic to have libnginx-mod-rtmp https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libnginx-mod-rtmp

You can install the rtmp lib from sources.